# How to zoom in/out an jpg image with actionscript?

Tags: flash, actionscript, image-processing

Is that kind of job easy to do in flash?

Answer (score 0):

depends on your definition of 'zoom'. but then i guess you can just use a really high def image, then show it small. to zoom it, just increase the dimensions of the image via width, height.

Comment: Sorry to mention late,I want to zoom partly.

Comment: so you just want to zoom in on a certain portion? yup just do an increase in width + height, then just show a portion of that using a mask.

Comment: Zooming images by mere scaling is not much of a good idea. 1. it performs poorly, 2. as soon as the bitmap is scaled to exceed 5000 px (width or height) it is no longer rendered. The best way to do this is to copy the visible pixels into a new BitmapData and scale that one.